# Simulate inline-block with React Native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

does anyone know how to simulate display: inline-block with React Native?

Basically I'd like to add a display: inline-block to the created style.

Example:

[image]

My purpose is to avoid the "3 days ago" here above split in 2 lines when the message before is too long.

Thanks!

[EDIT]
So here's my React Native code:

```
<View style={styles.contentContainer}>
    <Text>
        <Text style={styles.content}>{notification.content}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.created}>   {moment(notification.created, "YYYY-MM-DD[T]hh:mm:ss").subtract(n, 'hours').fromNow()}</Text>
    </Text>
</View>
```

And here's the relevant CSS corresponding:

```
contentContainer: {
    flex: 1,
},
content: {
    textAlign: 'left',
    fontSize: 14,
},
created: {
    textAlign: 'left',
    fontSize: 10,
    color: '#777777',
},
```

Comment: Please show some of your relevant code, so we will be able to help you

Comment: I've just edited my post to do so, thanks for your help :-)

Comment: works just fine as is: https://rnplay.org/apps/RgpZ5w

Comment: Maybe I was unclear or maybe I didn't understand what you did, so I clarified my question above...

Comment: got you, take a look at my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main change is to add `flexWrap: 'nowrap'` to `created` style.

Working example: https://rnplay.org/apps/RgpZ5w

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!